Counting interleavings of sequential processes with simultaneous events
Consider the 4-step process $abcd$ and the 3-step process $xyz$. The processes run concurrent and can interleave at any point, but must execute in sequence. How many possible interleavings are there?
There's a really cute way to calculate this: there are $7!$ permutations of $abcdxyz$, but only $\frac{1}{4!}$ of them have those have $abcd$ in the right order, and only $\frac{1}{3!}$ of those have $xyz$ in the right order. The same argument applies to the general case of $k$ processes each with $n_k$ steps, giving us the elegant answer of
$$ 
\frac{\left(n_1+n_2 + \ldots+n_k\right)!}{n_1! \, n_2! \, \ldots \, n_k!} 
$$
Now consider the same problem, except two processes can take a step simultaneously. So $axbyczd$ is a different interleaving from $a[xb]yczd$. If there were three processes $\{ab,pq,xy\}$, then both $[ap]xbqy$ and $[apx]bqy$ would be distinct interleavings. Is there a general formula for finding the number of total interleavings?
I brute-forced some of the values and found that for the special case of two processes, the values map to the Delannoy numbers.

It is clear why the number of interleavings in the case of two processes is given by Delannoy numbers. Let me explain the relationship:
The Delannoy number $D(m,n)$ is defined as the number of paths in the grid $\mathbb N^2$ from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ where each step is north $(0,1)$ or northeast $(1,1)$ or east $(1,0)$. Let $a_1,\ldots,a_m$ be the $m$ steps in the first process, and $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ be the $n$ steps in the second process. Consider a Delannoy path. If the next step in the path is

north, map it to the next available step $a_i$ in the first process,
east, map it to the next available $b_j$ in the second process, and
northeast, map it to $[a_i b_j]$ where $a_i$ and $b_j$ are the next available steps in the two processes.

It is clear that this gives a bijection between a path and an interleaving of the two processes.

More generally, define $D^{(k)}(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ to be the number of paths in the grid $\mathbb N^k$ from $(0,\ldots,0)$ to $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ where each step is along a nonzero vector from the set $\{0,1\}^k$. It is easy to construct a bijection from the set of such paths to the interleavings of $k$ processes with $n_i$ steps in $i$th process.
An obvious recurrence relation for these numbers is
$$
D^{(k)}(n) = \sum_{\ell\in\{0,1\}^k:\ell\ne 0}D^{(k)}(n-\ell),
$$
where $n=(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ with $n_i>0$ for all $i$, and $D^{(k)}(0,n_2,\ldots,n_k) = D^{(k-1)}(n_2,\ldots,n_k)$, etc. I don't know if there's a simple way to solve these recurrences. I will update the answer if I have something more to say about it.

Update: The paper cited below gives an expression for $D^{(k)}(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$.
Caughman, John S.; Dunn, Charles L.; Neudauer, Nancy Ann; Starr, Colin L., Counting lattice chains and Delannoy paths in higher dimensions, Discrete Math. 311, No. 16, 1803-1812 (2011). ZBL1223.05124.
